# protractor .click() promise resolves before angular finished updating the related DOM element

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I got the problem that I want to update a field in my e2e test via a button. So I wait for the `.click()` to resolve but when it resolves, the value is still not updated. If I put a `browser.sleep(500)` in front of getting the value, it is updated nicely as expected.

Here is my code:

```
[...]
.then((cartItems) => {
    expect(cartItems).toBe(1)
    return page.assemblyCheckbox.click()
})
.then(() => {
    // if I do a browser.sleep(500) here it works well
    return page.totalPrice
})
.then((totalPrice) => {
    // start price before click
    console.log('startPrice: ', startPrice) 

    // should be the price after the update
    console.log('totalPrice: ', totalPrice) 
})
[...]
```

So, why is the `.click()` promise resolved before the value gets updated by angular? How can I get around this with not using a `browser.sleep()` as I want to avoid that.

Thanks in advance guys. Took me almost two days now. :-/

Comment: So the click event triggers an update on the page.totalPrice?

Comment: Exactly. It is adding something to it and I want to make sure that it is working.

Answer (score 1):

The logic of your code is sound, so this might be a problem with how the value is updated on the button click. If I would have to guess it's done asynchronously without using Angular "stuff" which Protractor knows to wait for.

If you don't wish to introduce explicit millisecond waits you could go something like:

```
[...]
.then(() => page.totalPrice)
.then((beforeUpdate) => 
    page.assemblyCheckbox.click()
        .then(() => 
            protractor.browser.wait(() => 
                page.totalPrice.then((afterClick) => afterClick !== beforeUpdate)),
                10000
            )
)
.then(() => page.totalPrice)
.then((totalPrice) => {
    console.log('startPrice: ', startPrice) 
    console.log('totalPrice: ', totalPrice) 
})
[...]
```

You might be able to refactor this to look better but the main idea is that you wait for the totalPrice value to change from its value from before clicking the assemblyCheckbox, and then continue with your test.

Comment: Not working. And you are not returning a promise to resolve in `.then(() => page.totalPrice)` aren't you?

Comment: "() => page.totalPrice" is returning page.totalPrice (which I assumed from your code is actually a promise). What's error are you getting?